Create virtual layer out of three tables
I have a problem with creating a virtual layer.
The issue is from a bad Database where the line geometry id is linked to non-geometry tables where the other information is included. In case this is a parent-child relation, with one parent with geometry and n-children with no geometry.
I wanted to create a new layer out of the 1:n relation to create n-times lines.
So far so good, but there is a third table, where the current attributes (type, name, etc) are  in.
table_1: geometry, ID
table_2: reference to ID, reference to attribute_ID
table_3: attribute_ID, attribute1, attribute2
so I want to see the attribute1 and attribute2 matched with the geometry from table_1.
To make this even harder, the reference-names form table_2 to table_1 has the same name (line_ID)
so the match must be:
table_1: "line_ID" to table_2 "line_ID" <--> "ID" to table_3 "attribute_ID"
I hope this is clearly described and someone is able to make an SQL expression out of it, cause I can´t do it.
